# Next.js / cookie is undefined

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js

First of all: sorry if this is a bad type of question, I just started learning web dev a few weeks ago and now hit a problem I can't come up with a solution.

It's a next.js app that only has basic CRUD functions (I'm following Brad Traversys next.js course on udemy)

In this component I want to make a request to my Strapi backend to fetch user data

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import { parseCookies } from '@/helpers/index'
import { API_URL } from '../../config'

const Dashboard = ({ events }) => {
    return (
        <Layout title='User Dashboard'>
            <h1>Your events</h1>
            {events && events.length && events.map((el, i) => <div>{el.name}</div>)}
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default Dashboard

export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
    const { token } = parseCookies(req)

    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/events/me`,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })

    const events = await res.json()

    return {
        props: {
            events
        }
    }
}
```

the helper method should extract the cookie from the request and return the token to getServerSideProps

```
import cookie from 'cookie'


    export function parseCookies(req) {
        console.log('///// REQ IN HELPER', cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie))
        return cookie.parse(req ? req.headers.cookie || '' : '')
    }
```

Instead of a token the method returns this

```
{
  _xsrf: '2|07438526|dd1d3c86869ab7209b159b127acbead9|1629292796',
  'username-localhost-8888': '2|1:0|10:1629300070|23:username-localhost-8888|44:OThhNzc0YWY4MTA4NDFmZWFlYWM3MWE2MmEyNmUzYjI=|5c1a7386f172dee14bf53281f3e3ba9a6fb7e1cf067e7438529ca8f4160214f6'
}
```

Here is an example of how I set the cookie (in this case after login):

```
import { API_URL } from '../../config/index'
import cookie from 'cookie'


export default async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const { identifier, password } = req.body

        const strapiRes = await fetch(`${API_URL}/auth/local`,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ identifier, password })
            })

        const data = await strapiRes.json()

        if (strapiRes.ok) {

            res.setHeader('Set-Cookie',
                cookie.serialize('token', data.jwt),
                {
                    httpOnly: true,
                    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
                    sameSite: 'strict',
                    path: '/'
                })

            res.status(200).json({ user: data.user })
        } else {
            res.status(data.statusCode).json({ message: data.message[0].messages[0].message })
        }
    }
    else {
        res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST'])
        res.status(405).json({ message: `Method ${req.method} is not allowed` })
    }
}
```

So as far as I got it the cookie should now be stored server side and put automatically into each request. Though the result I get from my cookie.parse() is caused by an undefined cookie, as far as I understand.
In other components getting the cookie from the header is no problem and works as it should - it's just in this dashboard-component where it does not seem to work.

Does anyone of you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake - for everyone else who got this problem, here is what I made wrong: The call of  cookie.serialize was wrong, the object with the options need to be an argument of cookie.serialize instead of setHeader

wrong version

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie',
                cookie.serialize('token', data.jwt),
                {
                    httpOnly: true,
                    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
                    sameSite: 'strict',
                    path: '/'
                })
```

working version:

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie',
                cookie.serialize('token', data.jwt,
                {
                    httpOnly: true,
                    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
                    sameSite: 'strict',
                    path: '/'
                }))
```

Answer (score 1):

And I found another problem that might help you to overcome that problem. I had another faulty cookie saved in my browser that made my application crash. After deleting this cookie everything worked as it should